# Parametrize Multi Select values in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am new to Jenkins and I'm still learning all the options that it provides. My goal is to have a Multi Select list with some values (e.g. 10 values) and those options that are selected in that list, to be parametrized in a separated variables. For example, if I have values foo, bar, foobar, baz, bar and I select 'foo' and 'bar', I expect to have those 2 variables values stored in separated variables for further use. Is that possible and how I can achieve it?